# Mindfullness or Self Consciousness (Introvert's Struggle)

Tags: vipassana, enlightenment, meditation-insight, meditation-hindrances, consciousness

I am trying to achieve consciousness and that is my target to achieve it,...

I am struck in **Strange State** .. as Bruce lee said, in Enter The Dragon:

***Its like a finger pointing away to the moon. Dont concentrate on the finger or you will miss all that heavenly glory***

This dialogue describes my mind state exactly, and i want to overcome this state..

So, i am stuck in a state, which is high self-consciousness state, and i feel stuck when i am going to do something in group of people or alone, i feel everyone is watching me, and i am literally freezing, and i dont know what to do next..

example: when i am opening a door, a thought strucks me, like my mind shift towards some body is watching me, or something gets reminded to me, and i cant move in the intended direction of what i want to do...

Any help regarding how to overcome this is greatly appreciated...

Comment: any inputs are greatly appreciated..

Comment: Hello and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have also a [*Help Center*](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) with useful resources for new comers.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on this sentence as it seems somewhat unclear; *"I am trying to achieve consciousness and that is my target to achieve it"*.

Comment: @Lanka I have to say that, i experienced consciousness, but its like a temporary spark(for few seconds), it is not in a stable state.. in which i can get hold of it and continue in being in that state.. that is my problem.. and more often i encounter the situation i described above.. And if  i feel frustrated because of this state...

Comment: @Lanka Previuosly, I used to meditate from childhood, now i stopped it, and i am in my twenties now, these days i am trying to be mindful, but not meditating, i feel very strong feeling that i should achieve consciousness

Comment: @Lanka Actually, i am facing this freezing state in social situations, when there are so many people around me, and also generally and basically, i am an introvert(from childhood itself), and dont like being around in social situations..

Comment: Thanks. I have made an answer to one of your comments and not the main question. I might address that at a later point in time or we can have a chat about it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear if you are doing some formal practice; if you do it regularly, you are likely to see the conditions more clear and learn to deal with them. The best is to do a retreat.

In the usual forms of vipassana  (Mahasi & similar I am familar with), you have an anchor (breathing, walking) and when something else comes to your mind (through the 6 sense doors -- western 5 senses plus mind, which includes thoughts, feelings, states of mind etc), you acknowledge/label/note/name what happened and come back to the anchor. This way you learn to (a) see what is there (b) let it go and come back to the anchor. Both points (a) and (b) are important; that's how you learn to deal with whatever happens.

In fact, various states of mind such as frozen, switched-off or dissociated are common. If you find yourself in a stuck state, you can use the "stuck" label to acknowledge that state, and *come back*. If you find yourself you want to get rid of that state (as you say), acknowledge that wanting and *come back*. The feeling of being watched is also a feeling you should acknowledge.

When you follow a condition (which the mind does automatically when you don't acknowledge it), you see that a whole drama unfolds: first you notice the stuckness, then you dislike it, then you want to get rid of it, then you perhaps remember that it happened many times and you get frustrated or desperate, then you think what you've done wrong so that it does not disappear, maybe you think there is something wrong with you in general etc etc. That is endless. Acknowledge it as soon as you can, as quickly as you can, and let it go. See what comes next. That's the practice, always coming back to the present.

Comment: Previuosly, I used to meditate from childhood, now i stopped it, and i am in my 20s now, these days i am trying to be mindful, but not meditating, i feel very strong feeling that i should achieve consciousness..

Comment: I have to say that, i experienced consciousness, but its like a temporary spark(for few seconds), it is not in a stable state.. in which i can get hold of it and continue in being in that state.. that is my problem.. and more often i encounter the situation i described above.. And if i feel frustrated because of this state...

Comment: Actually, i am facing this freezing state in social situations, when there are so many people around me, and also generally and basically, i am an introvert(from childhood itself), and dont like being around in social situations..

Comment: It does not matter if it is in social situations; these situations trigger something *in you* and practice will help you release that. Dunno what you mean by experiencing consciousness, but don't attach it. Try to see things for what they are, that brings relief and liberation. Do not change them in the first place, they will change by themselves and in different (and often better) ways than you want/imagine.

Answer (score 1):

@user2929.. now that you have told a bit more about yourself, I have to add this & edit my post. To tell you being an introvert is a blessing in disguise. It is a good thing. Just try to reflect on this… A person can say that he/she is shy and would sound as if it is bad. I do not think so. Only those who have the innocence and gentleness, who have the shyness and fear to do wrong are the fortunate few (ones who have Hiri & Othappa”). They are the ones who will see the Dhamma and walk the Noble Eight Fold Path if they put their mind to it.

People who do not seek large crowds tend to turn their attention inwards, and there are very few of them in the world today. Buddha has pointed out that they have a far greater chance of going to heaven and finding liberation.

Still I am not going to change what I said before. This is a higher goal for you, that you got to work towards. The day that you come to the realization that what you conventionally call a ‘person’ can be understood in terms of five aggregates of clinging, and that the sum of which must not be taken for a permanent entity, your awkward feeling of self-consciousness will vanish.  It is because you are now mindful of your true nature - that you are nothing but an amalgam of ever- changing phenomena.

If you do not acquire a thorough understanding of the five aggregates of clinging, you will not be able to  grasp the liberation process at work within you.  In reality you and I are nothing but an amalgam of the five aggregates of clinging. So please try to think it through.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the elaboration. I have based my answer on one of your comments;

> *"...Lanka I have to say that, i experienced consciousness, but its like a temporary spark(for few seconds), it is not in a stable state.. in which i can get hold of it and continue in being in that state.. that is my problem.. and more often i encounter the situation i described above.. And if i feel frustrated because of this state..."*

First of all, don't feel sorry or frustrated because you cannot stay in a certain state.

Instead understand, through insight meditation, that this is actually the *impermanent nature of conditioned phenomena* that you are experiencing. You cannot control anything as long as being in *Samsara*, i.e. the conditioned realm. Trying to control stuff is actually the source of your (and others) frustration.

All condition phenomena, whether mental or physical, follows a specific recipe/process. See drawing.

[image]

So when something comes into existence, it persists and then breaks up and falls apart. Even in the middle part of the process, i.e. the *Presence-part* the phenomena is already falling apart. It's already travelling towards its own disintegration. Nothing is stable. Everything is in a constant flux and no matter how hard one tries to hold onto the object, it will vanish as sand through ones fingers.

That is simply the nature of conditioned phenomena. One cannot really understand this through the process of thinking or intellectualization. Instead one has to practice insight meditation (Vipassana) and see with ones own eyes how phenomena arise, persist and disolves into nothingness. When the mind has seen that enough times it will begin to let go.

As the Buddha said; *"Having known the world's impermanence, They (disciples) made an end to suffering<sup>1</sup>"*.

Trying to grasp at things creates attachment and as long as there is attachment, one cannot be free. Having something as your target might instead become a hindrance, depending on the intensity of the craving. The mind is like a little child or a dog, you have to teach it over and over in order to develop and purify it.

Lastly, don't be too hard on yourself. Think about it, we are all in the same boat, trying to become free from Samsara. We are just on different steps on the path. Being born human is extremely rare. Being lucky enough to come in contact with the Dhamma is even more rare. You are here now and that means countless of life times of performing wholesome and meritorious deeds, e.g. the practice of *meditation*.

Let me know if you have any questions to what I wrote and I will try to answer you. If you are interested in the technique I practice, I will be happy to share it with you.

Lanka

---

<sup>1</sup> Samyutta Nikaya: Sagathavagga: Devaputtasamyutta: *Connected Discourses with Young Devas*, Bodhi trans, p. 139.

Comment: please share how to start vipassana meditation.. or the technique you use to achieve mindfulness.. if it would be helpful to me, then it is greatly appreciable.... if anything i do comes to fruition, i will share this experience with others...

Comment: sir, can i have brief chat with you, if possible.. my time is now night 9:10 pm(IST).. if possible, at what time could you be reachable..

Comment: Hello and sorry for my late reply. I'm in Greenland and the time here is now 7.58 morning time. I will be available at 16.00 Greenland time. I will create and invite you to a chat room that you can then join if you are available. If not, we could talk via email. My mail is on my profile page.